# How to use Regex to extract a string from a specific string until a specific symbol in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

## Question

Assume that I have a string like this:

```
example_text = 'b\'\\x08\\x13"\\\\https://www.example.com/link_1.html\\xd2\\x01`https://www.example.com/link_2.html\''
```

## Expectation

And I want to only extract the first url, which is

```
output = "https://www.example.com/link_1.html"
```

I think using regex to find the url start from "https" and end up '\' will be a good solution.

If so, how can I write the regex pattern?

I try something like this:
`

```
re.findall("https://([^\\\\)]+)", example_text)

output = ['www.example.com/link_1.html', 'www.example.com/link_2.html']
```

But then, I need to add "https://" back and choose the first item in the return.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: why not you just use `output[0]` to get only first link?

Comment: @JayPeerachai they stated that they also want "https://" which their regex doesn't capture. `output[0]` isn't a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex a bit.
**What you were doing before:**
`https://([^\\\\)]+)` this matches your link but only captures the part after `https://` since you used the capturing token after that.

**Updated Regex:**
`(https\:\/\/[^\\\\)]+)` this matches the link and also captures the whole token *(escaped special characters to avoid errors)*

**In Code:**

```
import re
input = 'b\'\\x08\\x13"\\\\https://www.example.com/link_1.html\\xd2\\x01`https://www.example.com/link_2.html\''
print(re.findall("(https\:\/\/[^\\\\)]+)", input))
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.example.com/link_1.html', "https://www.example.com/link_2.html'"]
```

You could also use `(https\:\/\/([^\\\\)]+).html)` to get the link with `https://` and without it as a tuple. *(this also avoids the ending `'` that you might get in some links)*

If you want only the first one, simply do `output[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
match = re.search(r"https://[^\\']+", example_text)
url = match.group()
print(url)
```

output:

```
https://www.example.com/link_1.html
```